# Are HP Gen7 servers compatible with g6 drives?

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant

I have server g7 dl380. I want to check if i can put drives from server g6 and this will work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Yes they are compatible. The drive carrier is the same across generations... The part numbers are the same across generations.

Answer (score 0):

Your only concerns may be a needed firmware update depending on which controller you are connecting them to. New controller firmware will flag the disks for firmware upgrade.

Some newer controllers may have dropped support for the older disk models as well, but they would likely still work without being on the approved list.

Other than that, the drives should work normally. They may even still be configured in the same raid array if the new controller recognizes the metadata on the old disks.